# Exhaustive `match` against a bounded random number

Tags: f#

```
open System

let random_number_generator = System.Random(int System.DateTime.Now.Ticks) in
let random_number_below n = random_number_generator.Next(n) in
match random_number_below 3 with
| 0 -> "Zero!"
| 1 -> "One!"
| 2 -> "Two!"
;;
```

The above match statement is not exhaustive, according to the compiler. This is totally legitimate, as F# has no syntactical information that would guarantee the bounds of the random number.

```
Incomplete pattern matches on this expression. For example, the value '3' may indicate a case not covered by the pattern(s).
```

What were the idiomatic F# way of matching (or is it simply if-else'ing) against a random number?

Comment: would not it be enough to add a default (_ ->) clause? Either raising an exception or putting an empty string...

Comment: Oh it would be "enough" for sure. Is that the "right thing to do"? :)

Comment: Note that fixing this in the general case requires solving the halting problem and can't be done

Comment: Maybe it's relevant: I'm trying to select randomly among types in a distributed union.

Comment: I think probably the most idiomatic thing would be to do `|_ -> failwith "RNG is broken"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As in the comments, solving this in general requires solving the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).  As a result the best thing to do is probably

```
|_ -> failwith "broken RNG"
```